# RDP into Windows Server 2019 stuck on "Unlock the PC" screen

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server, lock-screen, windows-server-2019

I need to RDP into a Windows 2019 server. Occasionally, when my RDP session is closed or times out I will be prompted with an "Unlock the PC" screen after attempting to reconnect. From this point I'm essentially locked out of my server and I need to bug IT and they usually have to reboot it before I can successfully RDP back in. Obviously, this is less than ideal and there has to be a better way. Hoping all of you windows nerds can help!

Comment: I assume you have used the RDP client's ability to send a CTRL+ALT+DEL keyboard command before rebooting the machine?  There really isn't a solution to this problem, IT has configured the server, to lock the session when the RDP client connection is lost.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will try to send a CTRL+ALT+DEL command the next time I'm experiencing this issue. It is unfortunate to here that this has been explicitly configured by IT... I do have admin privileges on the server though. Is there anything I can do to remove this setting?